# What is "MSIE 6 SmartLinksAddon"?

Tags: internet-explorer, caching, squid

My server logs show lots of requests from a user agent identifying itself as:

`is MSIE 8 SmartLinksAddon`

I haven't been able to find anything useful about *SmartLinksAddon* but the requests tend to come with a **via** header that provides some hints..

```
via => 1.1 web01.mashlogic.local:3028 (squid/2.7.STABLE9)
```

Is anyone familiar with the purporse of *SmartLinksAddon*?

Squid would indicate it has something to do with caching, but how does it affect the user's actual browsing experience?

---

I'm posting this here instead of ServerFault because it feels more related to browsers rather than servers.